# changing value of activerecord attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a problem and I am not sure how can I resolve it...

lets say I have a class User < ActiveRecord::Base and I have attribute factor:int that is my database, and I can access this atribute with User.find(x).factor.

Now, I have another table where i have changed_attributes, but not for all users.

So I want to rewrite attribute factor: when there is an entry in changed_attributes with user id, User.factor would be new, and if not, old factor would be returned.

I know this works:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def factor
    newfact=20
    newfact
  end
end
```

but I dont know how to access old factor variable?
thank you
Dorijan
edit:
I have found the solution: read_attribute(:factor)

Comment: I have found the solution: read_attribute(:factor)

Comment: If you've found an answer, fill it in below and mark it as the accepted answer. That will help anyone coming along in the future.

Comment: what @Ted means with bellow is to write the answer bellow and not in your add it to your question